# Locus described by the centre of circles

Tags: geometry

Given a segment AB on the plane let $r$ and $s$ parallel lines with $A \in r$ and $B \in s $. What is the locus of the circles tangent to $AB$, $r$ and $s$? 
How could I solve this analytically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's choose the coordinate system with $(0,0)$ at the center of $AB$, with the length of $AB=2d$, such that $A=(0,d)$ and $B=(0,-d)$ (both on the $y$-axis). The lines $r$ and $s$ are described by the angle $\theta$ that they make with the $x$ axis. Then the center of any circle tangent to $r$ and $s$ will be on the line parallel to them, that goes halfway between those (therefore through the origin). The distance between the center line and either $r$ or $s$ is the radius of the circle tangent to the lines $$R=d\cos\theta$$ We know the equation of the halfway line $$\tan\theta=\frac yx$$
The last thing we need is that the circle is also tangent to the $AB$ line. Since $AB$ is along $y$ axis, it means that the radius of the circle at the tangent point is perpendicular to it, so it means parallel to the $x$ axis. That means that the $x$ coordinate of the circle center is $$x_c=R=d\cos\theta$$ Then it follows that $$y_c=d\cos\theta\tan\theta=d\sin\theta$$
Squaring the last two equations, and adding them will get rid of $\theta$: $$x_c^2+y_c^2=d^2$$
So the locus of the centers of the circles tangent to the $r$, $s$, and $AB$ lines is the circle with the diameter $AB$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the circle is tangent to $r$, $s$ and $AB$, its centre is equidistance from all three lines.  So construct the (internal and external, depending on how you choose your angle) angle bisectors of $\angle(AB,r)$, and of $\angle(AB,s)$.  Hence you have two points $O,O'$ which are the centres of the circles.

Answer (score 1):

Analitically wise,

- determine the unit vector $\bf u$ parallel to given lines;
- determine the middle line between the given two ;
- determine the half-distance between the given lines, which is the radius of the circle;
- determine the unit vector $\bf v$ parallel to segment AB,
- choose point $A$ as base, and determine the lines departing from it with directions given by the vectors $({\bf u} +{\bf v}) /2$ and $({\bf u} -{\bf v}) /2$;
- the crossings of the last two lines with the middle one are the centers of the two circles.